# issues with path using html hyperlink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

ASP.NET application on the default page I have to create two links that refer to PDF files.

Example:

`<a href="Private/UserDocs/SIPCustomerUserGuideV2-2013.pdf" target="_blank">`

Code structure where the PDF file exists is:

```
Web.FormProject/Private/UserDocs/SIPCustomerUserGuideV2-2013.pdf
```

Above Web.FormProject is a folder, Private is a sub folder in Web.FormProject and UserDocs is a sub folder under Private folder. And the file resides in UserDocs.

When I try using the above the URL gives me nothing not even an error.
But when I change my hyperlink to 
after putting the file in the Web.Form project (and not under any sub folder) it works fine.

I have even tried the same with asp:hyperlink does not work.
 It only worked when I tried it with asp:LinkButton with code in the server side but the Content:Disposition "inline: ... in the  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=SIPCustomerUserGuideV2-2013.pdf");    opens it in the same browser and I want it to open in a new browser" But I would like a solution to use it as a  hyperlink given above. Please reply.
Question:

How do I make it the PDF open from the  Web.Form Project/Private/UserDocs/path.
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Private/Docs/UserGuide.pdf") %>' target="_blank">Link To PDF</a>
```

The [ResolveUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will resolve to the full path.

**EDIT**

After some chat we found out he had a configuration:

```
<location path="Private"> 
<system.web> 
<authorization> 
<deny users="?"/> 
</authorization> 
</system.web> 
</location>
```

That disable the users not logged in to download files.

Comment: I tried : <a href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Private/UserDocs/SIPCustomerUserGuideV2-2013.pdf") %>'target="_blank" >User Guide</a> still no luck. thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by no luck? An error? did not download? what did you get?

Comment: It did not open at all. Why would it open when I put the file in root. But does not open when I put the file in a sub folder.

Comment: Because you are not resolving the file path correctly. The ResolveUrl works like this: ResolveUrl("~/SubFolder/OtherSubfolder/File.PDF") where ~/ means the root.

Comment: As you see I did try that. But it still did not open.

Comment: @Ruruboy I have an idea, why don't you take a screenshot of the files and show us? It's probably better for us to see where the document is, related to the page. :)

Comment: I just sent you a screen shot.It is sitting in that folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41456/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-ruruboy)

Comment: Hanlet - Super thanks again for your effort and help. God Bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Try resolving it from the root and don't forget to add the runat attribute:

```
<a href="~/Private/UserDocs/SIPCustomerUserGuideV2-2013.pdf" 
    target="_blank" runat="server">Link</a>
```

Comment: Hi. When the page first load this is the URL in the browser:http://localhost:60837/LogOn.aspx. I tried doing what you said it still does not open the PDF instead it displays the same LogOn.aspx page.

Comment: Do you have name and password to login?

Comment: Yes I have name and password to login. But this does not require login. This is a PDF on the logon page which will open when you click it. Any ideas?